# Windows Makefile and Setting Environment Variable

Tags: windows, makefile

My Product is built using cygwin on Windows.
but Windows Tools does not understand cygwin path like /home/lib/
How do I set those variables during runtime , like can I set environment variable

set LIB_PATH=`cygpath -w /home/lib'

Something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a direct translation of Cygwin to Windows readable path by prepending the path of your Cygwin installation (ie, "C:/cygwin") to the Cygwin style path. Thus, "/home/lib" would become "C:/cygwin/home/lib". In your makefile, you can have a variable to prepend to all of your paths that is an empty string on non-Windows platforms but becomes the correct Cygwin path on Windows.